# Hibernate Idempotent Update

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, http-put, idempotent

I tried searching this over the net but in vain. Is there a way to use hibernate to perform an idempotent update.

One use case is to use HTTP PUT to update a specific field in the database via a REST API. So for example, if I have a database with columns : ***Id, Name, Phone, UpdateDate*** and I update the **Phone** field (of a specific **Id**) with the same value multiple times only my first action must update the **Phone**(and also change my **UpdateDate**). Subsequent updates must have no effect on the record (and **UpdateDate**).

While this can be implemented in an application by first getting the record and comparing it against my input value before performing an update. I was wondering whether Hibernate has any inbuilt features?

Comment: How is the UpdateDate set? If you are manually setting that and telling Hibernate to update the record then this will be seen as an update for the record.

Comment: @tkeE2036 right now I am doing it manually through a program. So when ever there is a "PUT" update, I check whether its a change and if so, I change the date.

Comment: See also this investigation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453690/hibernate-thread-safe-idempotent-upsert-without-constraint-exception-handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In hibernate if you get an object and try to modify one of it`s property and commit the transaction. Hibernate compares new values to the old values. Issues an UPDATE for all persistent properties of the entity **only if the new value of at least one of the property is different than the old value.**

Example:

1. Find EntityA by id. Hibernate issues a SELECT for the entity (and any non-lazy many-to-one entities), and it remembers the original values. `EntityA a = hibernateSession.find(EntityA.class, id);`
2. Set some property on entityA. `a.setPhone(newPhoneValue);`
3. Commits the transaction, triggering `hibernateSession.flush().` Hibernate compares new values to the old values. Issues an UPDATE for all persistent properties of x if the old and the new value of propertyB are different.

Issue an update like : `UPDATE entityA set phone=?, name=?, updateDate=? WHERE id=?`

If you want you can use [dynamic-update](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) and [dynamic-insert](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) in the mapping.

> dynamic-update (optional - defaults to false): specifies that UPDATE
>   SQL should be generated at runtime and can contain only those columns
>   whose values have changed.
>
> dynamic-insert (optional - defaults to false): specifies that INSERT
>   SQL should be generated at runtime and contain only the columns whose
>   values are not null.

With dynamic-update set to true hibernate will issue a `UPDATE` without the `name` column because it has not change.

`UPDATE entityA set phone=?, updateDate=? WHERE id=?`

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried the dynamic-update before. I'l try it out.

Comment: I have dynamic update true, but when an update query called in trigger, hibernate throws an exception after trying to update all the fields . How and why hibernate tries to run a query when a trigger is being called ?